# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '\xe2\x80\xaaE:

Tags: python

OS:  Windows10
Iam trying to convert xml files to csv
Below is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xmlutils.xml2csv import xml2csv    
converter = xml2csv("‪E:\\Downloads\\29th March abcFTP Files\\Mar18\\Mar18\\BOH_290318.xml", "‪C:\\Users\\hi\\Desktop\\boh111.csv", encoding="utf-8")

converter.convert(tag="item")
```

But it is throwing error as

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '\xe2\x80\xaaE:\\Downloads\\29th March halonix FTP Files\\Mar18\\Mar18\\BOH_290318.xml'
```

Xml file converted to a empty csv file ? for which i had data in xml
Anything wrong in my code.

Comment: try giving path like this : converter = xml2csv(r"‪E:\\Downloads\\29th March abcFTP Files\\Mar18\\Mar18\\BOH_290318.xml", "‪C:\\Users\\hi\\Desktop\\boh111.csv", encoding="utf-8")

Comment: You have an invisible character in that string. Set your cursor between the E and the quotation mark and press backspace/del a few times.

Comment: @PrakharVerma Thanks, but now it is throwing IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: '\xe2\x80\xaaC:

Answer (score 0):

You have hidden special characters in your paths, you need to copy this code and write path manually :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xmlutils.xml2csv import xml2csv
convertr = xml2csv("d:\\untitled\\note.xml", "d:\\text.csv")
print(convertr)

convertr.convert(tag="response")
```

Also tag must be equal to the xml tag you want to convert.Give main tag of xml if you want to convert the full xml.